# Is it possible non-Clustered Index while creating Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table tblPeople 
(
     sno int  primary key ,  
     Name nvarchar(50), 
     Gender nvarchar(10) , 
     Age int ,
     index IX_tblPeople_Age nonclustered(age)
)
```

I'm getting an error when executing above.

> Incorrect syntax near 'index'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Works for me 2016. Microsoft states it applies to 2014 and up.

Comment: It does not work for me in 2012, also an example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql doesn't  work either `CREATE TABLE t4( c1 int, c2 int, INDEX ix_1 NONCLUSTERED (c1,c2))  ` Same error message.

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql) this syntax should work starting with version 2014 of SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just use the traditional syntax of creating the index after the table?

```
CREATE TABLE tblPeople (
     sno int  primary key ,  
     Name nvarchar(50), 
     Gender nvarchar(10) , 
     Age int
) 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_tblPeople_Age ON tblPeople (age);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. But is there any possible query inside Brackets?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CREATE TABLE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql), this syntax works on 2014 versions of SQL Server and later. You can find the following piece of information in the article:

> ```
> INDEX *index_name* [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ] (*column_name* [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,... *n* ] )
> ```
>
> **Applies to**: SQL Server 2014 through SQL Server 2017 and Azure SQL
>   Database.
>
> Specifies to create an index on the table. This can be a clustered
>   index, or a nonclustered index. The index will contain the columns
>   listed, and will sort the data in either ascending or descending
>   order.

So if your version is prior to 2014 I would suggest this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE tblPeople (
 sno int  primary key ,  
 Name nvarchar(50), 
 Gender nvarchar(10) , 
 Age int
) 
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_tblPeople_Age ON tblPeople (age);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same result using inline syntax compatible with 2008 with

```
create table tblPeople 
(
     sno int  primary key ,  
     Name nvarchar(50), 
     Gender nvarchar(10) , 
     Age int ,
     Constraint IX_tblPeople_Age unique nonclustered(age, sno)
)
```

As `sno` will be the CI key and SQL Server always adds the clustered key to the keys of nonunique nonclustered indexes created on tables with a clustered index anyway.